# mod_rewrite matching wrong pattern

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

My `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^client/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ licensee/client/$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^licensee/(.*)/$ licensee/$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I visit `/client/asdf/` in my browser however, it uses the second rewrite rule instead of the first. If I comment out the second rewrite rule, it uses the first rule as expected.

I can't figure out how the second rule could possibly match `/client/asdf/` - have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you visit /client/asdf/, it matches the first RewriteRule, so a new request becomes "licensee/client/?id=asdf" which matches your second rule.

Comment: Does the L flag not stop that from happening? What would you recommend?

Comment: @Tak The L flag tells apache to stop processing the rewrite rule for the first request, and mark the new request as new, which match the second rule. It is better to add RewriteCond for your RewriteRule to avoid this.